# Simple SPA with Angular and Laravel API

Tags: php, api, angularjs, laravel

I want to create a really simple SPA with Angularjs and Laravel 4 as an API in the background. I'll have some simple posts and categories (a blog actually) with some static pages. I want to call laravel API inside angular to get the information I want. How can I organize the code to do it properly? Maybe put the laravel to a subdomain and the angular app to the main domain? Is it a good way? I want to separate these frameworks and use laravel only for api service. Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Trying to make sure I understand the question. You want to use laravel for the mvc, but instead of returning html views you just want it to take care of persistence and then return whether or not whatever operation your requested was successfully performed?

Comment: I want to do everything with angular and laravel is just a separated service to response the requests made by the angular app

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer below that I think answers your question. If there's anymore confusion I'd be happy to clarify as best I can.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [laravel's built in restful controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers) as a way of building your backend api.

Then you just have your angular js make ajax calls to [whatever route you define](http://laravel.com/docs/routing) to that controller. Then instead of having laravel return views using View::make, you have it return a [response](http://four.laravel.com/docs/responses) and I'm assuming returning json would be the best option. `return Response::json(array('userId' => '1', 'operation' => 'UpdateUser', 'success' => 'true'));`

Implemented this way, laravel acts strictly as an API and angular js acts as the intermediary between your user and the laravel api.